# Facebook / Google login for website with Federated Authentication

Tags: federated-authentication

We have a Sitecore 9 website, where we have set up Federated authentication to login to Sitecore using Facebook and Google. Logging into Sitecore using these social networks is working as expected.

[image]

Can anyone please point me to an example of how to integrate social login with the front end website? Previous versions using Social Connected Module had a rendering I could drop. How do we do this in Sitecore 9?

Comment: You will need to download it and follow the code, but the Sitecore 9 version of habitat has a social login built into it. https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/src/Feature/Accounts/code/Views/Accounts/_FedAuth.cshtml and https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/src/Feature/Accounts/code/Repositories/FedAuthLoginButtonRepository.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Habitat v9 branch has a working example of how to implement this. Blog available here:

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/habitat-federated-authentication-for-sitecore-9

> The Feature.Accounts module configures the use of the Facebook
>   provider, but it will also show additional buttons to any providers
>   you configure in the config file:
>
> https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/src/Feature/Accounts/code/App_Config/Include/Feature/Feature.Accounts.config